# SQL Server export using PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm re-doing a website for a client who currently is using Umbraco.

The previous developer upped and disappeared and left us with pretty much nothing, I need to get to the templates to redo it, but it seems the templates are stored in the database.

The server has PHP on it as well as .NET to run Umbraco.

I don't know .NET and am quite shady with PHP ... I have the entire source code for the Umbraco install which means I have database name, userid, password and host.

Is there a script in PHP someone can help me with which can dump the entire contents of the SQL Server database so I can search through it and get the templates out.

Ive tried using RazorSQL to connect to the SQL Server database, but it won't let me connect for some reason.

Any help would be great.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what version of Umbraco it is?

The templates for umbraco are stored on the disk in the MasterPages folder in v4 and later.

If you need access to the backoffice in Umbraco and have the db username and password (found in the web.config file) you could reset the password in the db (table = umbracoUser) as long as membership provider is set to not hash the passwords. This can be checked by looking in the web.config file at the lines

```
<add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="umbraco.providers.UsersMembershipProvider" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="false" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
```

if the passwordFormat="Hashed" remove that attribute.   This will enable you to set the password in the db to be clear text.

once this is done you should be able to login to the back office of umbraco by going to

```
http://[yoursitedomain]/umbraco/umbraco.aspx
```

Hope this helps you out :)  Otherwise the friendly folks over at http://our.umbraco.org should be able to shed light on any other issues you might have.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the comment .... It seems its running Umbraco 3 from the login screen .... are the templates still stored on disk for this verison?

Comment: Ahhh no in v3 the templates are stored in the database.   They also use different syntax.   However you still could change the admin password in the database to gain access to the back office.

Comment: I had a look in the config file and couldnt find the line you specified .... is this a good thing? ... is there any way you could guide me through the steps to changing the password? ... it would be a great help ... cheers

Comment: The reason that you dont see that line is because you have version 3 and the passwords are not hashed and are cleartext in the database.